# Can Google Sheets scrape Google docs for information?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-docs

I know it's possible to scrape websites but is it possible to have Google Sheets scrape a Google Doc for data? For example, if I have a bunch of google docs and they all have a line that says last updated: mm/dd/yyyy .  Is it possible to have a google sheet with urls to the docs and have them scrape for the date

Comment: Although I'm not sure about the actual situation of `a bunch of google docs` and your actual Google Document, when a script is used, the values of `last updated: mm/dd/yyyy` and the URL of the Google Document can be retrieved. So I think that your goal can be achieved using a script. In this case, only the built-in functions in Google Spreadsheet cannot achieve your goal. It is required to prepare the script with also Google Document service and/or Google Docs API. If this was not the direction you think, I apologize.

Answer (score 1):

## Solution

> With the use of a script in your Spreadsheet you can actually retrieve information from any document of your drive. With the `DocumentApp` class in Apps Script you can actually retrive the body of your document with [this method](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/document#getbody). Moreover, you can make searches using the `findText()` method of the `Body` class as shown [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/body#findtextsearchpattern).

Therefore yes, with a script you could easily search a document for a sepecific text pattern like yours `mm/dd/yyyy`.

For more info about the DocumentApp functionallities [check this documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document).

I hope this has helped you. Let me know if you need anything else or if you did not understood something. :)